# After user defined event, wait for other outside event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend, web-frontend

I have a query that is running in the background to retrieve all the user emails from a large database collection.

The user can enter their email address into a field and click submit, but the query getting all email accounts might not complete yet, and we want to make sure the user defined email address has not already been taken.

After the user clicks submit, how can I wait for the query to return?

Comment: You could attach the handler for the form submit only when the background query has finished. If you are not using a handler for the form submit, then only add the `type="submit"` attribute to the form once the query is finished.